# SQL Query not showing expected result what i want

Tags: sql, oracle

I hope everyone doing well,

I just do one query and i expect the result like this :

[image]

But what i have totally different :

[image]

my Query :

```
WITH temp AS
  (SELECT job_id,count(sap_docno)
  FROM tbl_sap
  WHERE job_id in (86933432321 
)
  
  GROUP BY 
    job_id
  
  )
SELECT job_id,
  rm.reme_filename
FROM TBL_xml_LOG@RM_LINK.WORLD rm
JOIN temp t
ON rm.rem_job_id =t.job_id
GROUP BY job_id,
  rm.reme_filename
ORDER BY job_id,
  rm.reme_filename;
```

any advice or idea ?

Comment: If you want to count something, I would expect a `COUNT()` (or perhaps `SUM()` in your query.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need to add count in your final query. You can try below query -

```
WITH temp AS (SELECT job_id,count(sap_docno) cnt
                FROM tbl_sap
               WHERE job_id in (86933432321)
               GROUP BY job_id)
SELECT job_id,
       rm.reme_filename,
       cnt
  FROM TBL_xml_LOG@RM_LINK.WORLD rm
  JOIN temp t ON rm.rem_job_id =t.job_id
 ORDER BY job_id, rm.reme_filename;
```

Comment: it is repeat the cnt for all the job and file name :(

Answer (score 0):

Query you posted wouldn't return ANY result as it is invalid.

Anyway:

- you "forgot" to include the "count" function's result (from a CTE) into the final `SELECT`
- `IN` is incomplete; I just fixed it so that it looks OK
- `GROUP BY` is out of the CTE; should be within
- the last `GROUP BY` is here for ... what, exactly? Maybe you wanted to use `DISTINCT`? Can't tell.

When fixed, without any sample data, this is what *might* do what you wanted:

```
WITH temp AS
  (SELECT job_id,
          count(sap_docno) as cnt
   FROM tbl_sap
   WHERE job_id in (86933432321) 
   GROUP BY job_id  
  )
SELECT 
  t.job_id,
  rm.reme_filename,
  t.cnt
FROM TBL_xml_LOG@RM_LINK.WORLD rm JOIN temp t ON rm.rem_job_id = t.job_id
ORDER BY t.job_id, rm.reme_filename;
```

---

BTW, why do you need a subquery (or a CTE)? Why not an ordinary join?

```
select t.job_id, 
       rm.reme_filename,
       count(*) cnt
from tbl_sap t join tbl_xml_log@rm_link.world rm on rm.rem_job_id = t.job_id
where t.job_id in (86933432321)
group by t.job_id, rm.reme_filename
order by t.job_id, rm.reme_filename;
```

Comment: Okay but i need to group by rm.reme.filename , how can this be , because this query repeat the cnt for all

Comment: No idea, you didn't provide any sample data. Maybe because query contains **only** JOB_ID = 86933432321? Though, I edited the answer and posted another option which doesn't have a subquery at all. Have a look.